# robocopy command not working with ms access files

Tags: backup, robocopy

I'm looking for incremental backup of one of my folders in my USB flash drive to my pc
I'm using a ROBOCOPY command and has scheduled it on log on event through task scheduler

Here's the code I'm using in my bat file

ROBOCOPY "I:\MJDrive" "d:\DriveBackup" /e /z /xo /tee /mt:4 /R:10 /W:10 /xf /LOG:d:\Backup.log

Every thing is working fine with the other files except of the ms access files actually which I'm working on and especially which I'm doing all this for.

Why does it not work with ms access files.
Please help.

Comment: This is a question for the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) website.

Comment: It's not that this doesn't work with Access files... it doesn't work on files **which are are open**, and you said these are `files actually which I'm working on`.  Regardless, this isn't a programming question.  See the [help/on-topic] for information about what's on-topic on this site, as well as the [tour] and "[ask]". Good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry for inconvenience friend but obviously when i log out of system and login again, obviously all my files are closed. What i meant by this was that I'm working on a number of access and other files which i want to keep backed up

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me out. 
I found the solution to my question and i thought the knowledge's worth sharing

Here is my complete code which I've found the perfect for the job and convenient

@echo on
ROBOCOPY "I:\MJDrive" "d:\DriveBackup" /e /z /xo /tee /mt:4 /R:5 /W:5 /it /LOG:d:\Backup.log
start "" "D:\Backup.log"

1- I like to keep the echo on to be able to have a look at any time on whats going on

2- The /it option is the real charm to handle the database type of files to stay updated

3- Finally it opens the log file to show the details of operation just done.

Hope it contributes to someone else.